# Need to show MODALPOPUP Extender while clickig on Link button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Need to show MODALPOPUP Extender while clickig on Link button and in modal pop up extender we need to get send an email to the required mail ID holder.

Is there any specifications and functionality to use in ASP.NET with C#.Please suggest me the best.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried to do this??? what your question concern sending email or opening madalpopup... for sending email in asp.net there are lots of question.. for better answer write correct question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add below mentioned namespace in code behind of aspx page from which you want to send the mail.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
      mail.To.Add("Email ID where email is to be send");
      mail.To.Add("Another Email ID where you wanna send same email");
      mail.From = new MailAddress("YourGmailID@gmail.com");
      mail.Subject = "Email using Gmail";

      string Body = "Hi, this mail is to test sending mail"+ 
                    "using Gmail in ASP.NET";
      mail.Body = Body;

      mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
      smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
      smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
           ("YourUserName@gmail.com","YourGmailPassword");
    //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
      smtp.EnableSsl = true;
      smtp.Send(mail);
    }
```

**For sending mail try the above code in C#**

opening the Modalpopup extender on button click

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="hiddenButton" />
/div>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderID" runat="server"
  BehaviorID="ModalPopupBehaviorID"
  TargetControlID="hiddenButton"
  PopupControlID="ModalContainer"
  />

...

//Javascript
var modalPopupBehaviorCtrl = $find('ModalPopupBehaviorID');
modalPopupBehaviorCtrl.show();
```

Comment: okay thank you for suggestion but need to show modal pop up extender by clicking on link button and then this code comes inhandy..please suggest me

Comment: hello mam,i have used this code but nothing is showing over there.kindly listen my problem i have link button by clicking that i need to get modal pop up extender.i am just a starter...